# Delete leading characters from multiple lines

Tags: regex

pls see the below example, I need to retain only those characters that are succedded by RA: on all the lines and i need to delete all values upto RA:

so for example
FP: 0x33A173D0, RA: 0x947BD1C should yield me 0x947BD1C  the pattern of these characters are usually the same, they begin with FP: ,two white spaces,followed by hex values and then a comma with two white space and then RA: I extremely new to regex since I do this repetively in my job someone suggested that I do this by regex but they did not know how.. and neither do I. so I am looking for help here

```
FP: 0x33A173D0, RA: 0x947BD1C
FP: 0x33A173F0, RA: 0x895AA8C
FP: 0x33A17400, RA: 0x8934DD0
FP: 0x33A17430, RA: 0xA3C6990
FP: 0x33A17438, RA: 0xA3C6C10
FP: 0x33A17448, RA: 0xA3C6F4C
FP: 0x33A17480, RA: 0xA68769C
FP: 0x33A17498, RA: 0xA8097A4
FP: 0x33A174F8, RA: 0x9DE4410
FP: 0x33A17528, RA: 0x8E01CD8
FP: 0x33A17548, RA: 0x8E02D1C
FP: 0x33A17560, RA: 0x8E0497C
```

Comment: For which RegEx environment do you need it? In vi: ":1,$s/.*RA: //" As your data seems to be hex-numbers, RA: wouldn't be contained in it, so removal of .*RA: would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are reading those values line by line, then you can use

```
.*RA:\s*(.*)$
```

and replace with

```
$1
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?323j0)

Comment: thanks all of you for the answer, the above answer by stema worked out really nice....

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
^(.*?RA: )
```

and replace matched group with empty string. Or match:

```
^.*?RA: (.*)$
```

to get your final content.

Comment: Your first regex will never match.

Comment: Because it doesn't allow anything after `RA: `.

Answer (score 0):

Python example:

```
result = re.sub(r"(?m)^.*,\s*RA:\s*", "", subject)
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?m)    # Multiline mode
^       # Match start of line
.*      # Match any number of characters
,\s*    # Match a comma, followed by optional whitespace
RA:\s*  # Match "RA:", followed by optional whitespace
```

Answer (score 0):

In your text editor that supports REGEX(such as vim, UltraEdit), find

```
FP: +0x[0-9A-F]+, +RA: +(0x[0-9A-F]+)
```

replace with

```
$1
```

or in some special editor(such as Crimson Editor, EditPlus) should replace with

```
\1
```